# Consecutive repetitions in Python

Tags: python

I'm new in proggraming so don't be cruel to me :) I'm struggling with problem of the highest number of consecutive repetitions in a string. I'm given a substring for example "ABC", then I have a file with sequences of letters ex. "ABC ABC BBC CDA ABC ABC ABC DBA"(here spaces not included,used only for better look). Here output should be 3, this is the highest number of repetitions one after another.

I'm thinking of using `str.count(sub[, start[, end]]` method, but I have no idea how to use it in order to have valid output. I've been trying to create substring s = string[i][j] and then use s2 which is `string[i+len(substring):j+len(substring)]` but it seems too much cases so I gave up on it. Using code below I had valid output but only in few cases. I hope you'll help me with it. Thanks!

```
substr_count = 0
string = "ABCABCBBCCDAABCABCDBA"
while True:
    start = 0
    substring = "ABC"

    loc = string.find(substring,start)
    if loc == -1:
        break
    substr_count += 1
    start = loc + len(substring)
```

Comment: You are just counting the number of occurrences. You need to find sets of *consecutive* occurrences, then return the length of the longest one.

Comment: You could store your substr_count in a list and keep on updating the values in the list.

Comment: The most pythonic way would be to split the string in sets of 3 characters and then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Not submitting this as an answer, though, because it looks like You Are Not Quite There (Yet).

Comment: You probably want to move `start = 0` to be above the loop.

Comment: @usr2564301`groupby` is probably not general enough because occurrences don't necessary start at group boundaries, for example: `"ABC"` occurs in `"XABCX"` but you can't find it if you group it into sets of 3 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usr2564301 said, `itertools.groupby` would be the way to go.
Here's a silly, kind of brute-force-ish way to go about it:

```
def max_repititions(string, substring):
    if not substring:
        return 0
    for count in range(len(string), 0, -1):
        if substring*count in string:
            return count
    return 0

string = "ABCABCBBCCDAABCABCDBA"
substring = "ABC"

print(max_repititions(string, substring))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with only three lines of code using regular expressions.

```
import re

string = "ABCABCBBCCDAABCABCDBA"

string_regex = re.compile(r'(ABC)*')
in_a_row = string_regex.search(string)
substr_count = len(str(in_a_row[0])) / len('ABC')
print(substr_count)
```

import re like you would any other package, define the string, put whatever you want to find in that string where the (ABC) is now and go.

This works by searching a given string, in this case named 'string' for any number of repeating (that's what the asterisk is for) strings you define in the parenthesis.
Then simply take the length of in_a_row and divide it by the length of the string you asked it to find and you will be left with a numerical output of how many times it repeats.

Comment: I don't think this is right. If you change the string to `"ABCABCBBCCDAABCABCABCDBA"`, then the answer should be 3, but your code gives two. It could be fixed by using `finditer()` and also changing the regex from `(ABC)*` to `(ABC)+`, and then keep the maximum count.